# PDF Creation with an SVG with curved text in PHP - no text is shown

Tags: php, pdf, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm working on a project right now which requires me to render out a PDF including an SVG with curved text written on it.

The text needs to be created this way as it has to be available in multiple languages and has a variable in it.

By now, I got the PDF to be rendered out the way I want it, except for the curved text, which just gets ignored.

This is the SVG I try to render out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="1024px" width="1280px" id="mainSVG">
    <defs>
        <path d="m250,250 a10,10 0 0 0 350,250" id="curvedTextPath"></path>
        <path d="m250,250 a10,10 0 0 1 350,250" id="curvedTextPath2"></path>
</defs>
    <circle style="fill: blue;" cx="425px" cy="375px" r="250" id="mainCircle"></circle>
    <text>
        <textPath startOffset="55%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#curvedTextPath">Some test text that is longer</textPath>
        <textPath startOffset="22.5%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#curvedTextPath2">Smaller text here</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

I tried converting the SVG with Imagick, which gives me only the circle without the text:

```
    <?php
    $svg = file_get_contents("/path/to/test.svg");
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImageBlob($svg);
    $image->setImageFormat("png");
    $image->writeImage("/path/to/lobster.png");
    ?>
```

Same goes for the ImageMagick command "convert" and TCPDF's "imageSVG"-function:

```
require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->setAuthor('Test');
$pdf->setTitle('Curvetest');
$pdf->setSubject('Testing of the Curve');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->imageSVG($file = './test.svg', $x = 15, $y = 30, $w = '', $h = '');
$filepath = '/path/to/test.pdf';
$pdf->Output($filepath, 'F');
```

I'm out of ideas by now, I have read that ImageMagick ignores textPath when converting, but if libRSVG is installed, it should work... well, it is, but it still doesn't work.

- Does anyone have an idea of how to deal with this?
- Maybe a different approach I didn't think of yet?

Comment: by the way, the values inside the path tags are a bit weird because we played around with the numbers this afternoon to figure out how the path tag works

Comment: I just tried using inkscape just now. It works a bit better in actually showing the text on the textpath, but doesn't read the text path correctly. Only one of the two texts is showing in a totally different spot, backwards and with a bigger letter spacing.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same now

Comment: I did, i actually had to do it with javascript and i found a preexisting script, hope this helps with your problem: https://github.com/codrops/Arctext

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`inkscape`](https://inkscape.org/en/)** also from the command line. It will then not start a GUI even.

The following command will convert your SVG to PDF:

```
inkscape          \
 --without-gui    \
 --file=input.svg \
 --export-pdf out.pdf
```

The screenshot below is from the quoted SVG source (in the OP) after conversion to PDF:

[image: Screenshot of out.pdf]

To see more possibly useful parameters for an inkscape command, see `inkscape --help`.

### Update

BTW, ***my*** version of ImageMagick (MacPorts version on OSX Mavericks) had no problem to convert the SVG to PDF:

```
$ convert -version

  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
  Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
  Features: DPC Modules
  Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib


convert input.svg out2.pdf
```

Here is the resulting PDF's screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of out2.pdf]

Comment: Hello Kurt, thanks for your reply! The PDF you got out of inkscape and imagick is exactly the one i get aswell, in both of them, the text is totally out of place. It should be at the bottom of the circle, inside it. I don't know what causes this problem, and by now, I am trying out to do this with CSS3 or SASS, this could be fun x)

Comment: @PhilippT.: Check your SVG code then. For me, the PDF output looks exactly like the SVG rendered by Inkscape: the text string is outside the circle, not inside.